# IIS 7.5 and DNS Configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, iis-7.5, bindings

I'm trying to configure a Windows 2008 R2 Server (Web Server); I know how to access the websites using different ports using IIS, but not when giving them hostnames (in IIS).

I have absolutely no idea how the DNS is supposed to work in relation to IIS. To go this far, you'd almost need to do a [Microsoft Training (like Exam 70-642)](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-642) in order to understand these things and how they are to be configured.

If someone can help and put me on the right track with some proper sources, I'd at least have some proper understanding of this - and even more, how you could easily configure your DNS to work with IIS, both in production and in a test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want DNS to do?

On the DNS server, add an "A" record pointing to the IIS server's IP address, e.g.

```
www.mysite.example.org -> 192.168.0.10
```

On the IIS server, right click on the site, choose "Bindings", and add hostname "www.mysite.example.org". Listen on either 192.168.0.10, or all addresses.

You can keep doing that - adding more sites listening on the same address and port, separating them by name. IIS will serve up whichever site the browser requests in the HTTP GET request.

Comment: I think I figured it out. My configuration wasn't set right. The preferred DNS server was set to another server other than the one I was configuring for IIS! I used nslookup to see what was happening. Does the "Alternate DNS server" only become available when the "Preferred DNS server" doesn't work? I thought it would go from one to the other. Its working now, if you have any additional comments, let me know.

Comment: If you mean in Windows network card settings, yes I think it asks the first one always, and the second one only if the first one doesn't reply.